# How to solve Apple LLVM compiler 4.1 error?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, instagram

I am a beginner in iPhone developing. I want to integrate Instagram in my app and for that purpose I downloaded the api of Instagram from Github but it gives the error of Apple LLVM compiler 4.1 error Command
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Please give any suggestion which how to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

I found this is the simplest and step by step tutorial for integrate instagram in my iOS app

[**How To Create an App Like Instagram With a Web Service Backend – Part 1/2**](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13511/how-to-create-an-app-like-instagram-with-a-web-service-backend-part-12)

I had the same ARC problem but if you will follow this you will its so easy and helpful

btw *for the error you having just look below word*, in that page and see you need to made some changes in Xcode for Libs, and you will get it working.

**-fno-objc-arc**

Thanks to raywenderlich :)